# In iOS, how do I reference an object in a view that is created with a xib file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, xib

I have a view controller that is instantiated in appDelegate and pushed onto a navigation controller. The view controller's view is created with a xib file. The xib file puts a UILabel on the view (among other things). Now I need to set the label's text property programatically but I don't see how to get a reference to it. How do I reference the label object?

I'm using xcode 3.2.5 and building an iPad app.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Aside from `IBOutlets`, you can also set a tag property on the label in the IB. Then, when you need it you can do:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:111];
```

111 of course being the tag you assigned to the label in IB.

Comment: This is good. I never knew how to use tags and now I know. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you test the code provided above? Per Apple's documentation, viewWithTag returns a UIView—nothing else: "Returns the view whose tag matches the specified value." The runtime error confirms what the documentation states, in that it was expecting a view: 2016-03-13 17:28:40.961 LumaCoreData[5211:1212054] -[UIView value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d6dbc00
2016-03-13 17:28:40.962 LumaCoreData[5211:1212054] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d6dbc00'

Answer (score 9):

You do this with what's called an "outlet". You define them in your controller, mark them clearly as `IBOutlet` and then connect them in Interface Builder to your file owner (or other delegate object created in IB).

For instance, in your `FooController.m` you might have this:

```
@interface FooController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* fooLabel;
@end
```

Then you would select your label, and either control drag from it to the file owner, or go to its connections tab, and drag from the `+` under referencing outlet, to the file owner and select the `fooLabel`.

**UPDATE**: Code sample changed to reflect modern way of handling this case.

Comment: This is a good and helpful answer. Thank you. I would give it a green check but apparently I can't give checks to two different answers even though they are both good and I already checked another one.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.view viewWithTag:NUMBER_OF_TAG];` does the trick. But remember that if you want to access the view you must do it on the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear events.